# Unable to get connection from MSSql while trying with Spring Data R2DBS

Tags: sql-server, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I am using Spring Data R2DBS for MSSQL db.

I am trying to connect to an instance using Windows Authentication with JavaKerberos authentication, instead of some SQL Authentication.

When I am trying with JDBC using below property, I am able to get a connection:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://AAAAAA.bb.myapp\\ZZZZZ;databaseName=mydb;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

But when I am trying below property using R2dbs, I am getting the below exception:

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:mssql://AAAAAA.bb.myapp\\ZZZZZ;databaseName=mydb;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

Below is the exception am getting while trying with Spring Data R2dbc:

> Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: r2dbc://AAAAAA.bb.myapp\ZZZZZ;databaseName=mydb;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
> at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974) ~[na:na]

Can anyone please tell me how to fix for above issue?

Comment: "ZZZZZ" is your instance name?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  I actually modified actual hostname to ZZZZZ , I will be glad if you could able to help me fix on above issue..

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  AAAAAA.bb.myapp\ZZZZZ  , I think ZZZZZ   is an instance name, I think this is a comination of hostname and instance name...

Comment: I am not well versed in the spring/java side here.  On c# we use a connection string enclosed in quotes (or in a config file); good luck.